# Vega Tree Diagram - Ambiguous Value

Tags: charts, tree, vega-lite, vega

I've been working on creating a tree diagram in Kibana. Much like here: https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/tree-layout/

I am almost there, sometimes I can get a tree diagram, but other times I get an error "[Error] ambiguous: efg". Other times it works and produces a tree.

[Link to the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhCY6AGzhoQAUVLjMAAihsGGiNJAQaZcUnkHUAbVBmES9PKRM4Fw8XMMHmAE5eZTDTiACZooEE4DJjKsHBQANZMbAAeIAC+aVK2SPbKTgCeutEyHvJeynLB+YaBIWEgEVHKPkjB7IZsOHISllayNFWGUGUQmHA+IAC6GVkgdg4g8kHxBiWeC21IZBLmNUGhqOHikdHoEK5xxSCd3eK9i0FKMlAMPqSGm9tm8h0+9GxfXbTTLZXJnOA4JAtW7udZoABm5nOAX29UapxAsQSSVSGUmMmCSEwKGsoIWkJ8cA0sLKcF6oBePkpGgAcmxggsfGw2JgAJIAEUMFKpp3EDHk8jS01m8wqlKeIHhbB8yFOoBwXJw40w1XQWzIlIotwglGJTEUlCYDAScEwBkyshadyVKrQNlk+S1yhdCHFKBkcGSGuUhMwDAQlHicHylFG8QAjIYkJYjJgE+lZjqvegfX7DIHg+hQ+HI9HY2mAExJlNxqsgj3ZxXK31OfNBiZFoklqMxuMAZmryn7GdAWYWudbAfbIa7EeCbCgAH0dHorsmhzQAF5KKVrWmWUfc+JoeMANhkcnswUXRQRSLgMkXEBgUOCB9kPN2qD7Mgg1qgdIQPC4poD+RjxDQOBagcAAMMiIjQiiwQ6MB0O+mCfj8qAACwAOxgcgyRPjolJoGKEoyKhdputKID6oaRLsHc9Rmoo9RIPCYw+IuPb1HGiboImv6VsozhQIYw7oHWATWlG1GkiAvGHKm6boAOwnxFW6BQByElpgO6DYRmIDzkuK7Uqg8YaQJIDqSpWmYrpGkGSARm-luDjxvWSmgPxyh9vGdm1socDwmQenxC5AjGaZy66BZYF+WpgURQ5oXhc5yjRe526gd50Z8WmNkBUFInoOlEUuaeMULnFq5oBW1n+SlGlpWFlXKNVOUOBW+W6r5RX+VWrXKKhwgdeguE1WZ8WnFZKnFcN9mjTQ42ZZNEkeSefWFaptlLcFepMOJ60gNJJm1eZc1NWpB1lXRx0TWdm25ZZO3KUl+0ABypSF7WndFDqxVdDU3d9v3lf9KlRS9PXvQNe19hWP0jeg8TyAgT0-UDl2zSeYNIyjy1oxjWOw9twIzGSyg0GIThjMEiikPIQlGLoPgAXKcAKr4SDOs2bqjp65JcsIlyGPCNCuG+boLUMrzMpgbJORdM31fidH3IyivKwqwrUgSuPq-WY6iWQBp8GMhgGroOBMLqfT61c2sirrUzwVL8gy9Yqt1dSGudPcf6Yxr64+8DePSkLjYTv6mvKE7baFiAACEtP8qFjzBAAFMWEZOwAlJoAD8mgAORcjyApl6geeUInJvCwnovix70tawrrvsnrUIih8Rv+zIYd9C7rLd0KvcG77INRw246IVxScdiZs6UKPSvj1K9ayugtNsPTcCM3AzPxgAsuMZCHwA6nQMAAAqT1cYivJzPt7wfR8nxPitTNvOQLO-Ikh8mauAOuzV+jpuaGF5vzV0ClTboA1GwMWUAriS3brLPyI1DZq0HvHH2idnidzHirCOxtMxNz1ObBiVsZA2wYHbB2IBCGYmIRvXSGt0Fe3uGQvBgdMHhndvgvovDoizwQcwluqCJae29iPNhbsZAsNEUI4erCmRdxVsogeYjG4xwXuMJeM4wwRnXm7PR895CLynMnOuDdZ47waHTIBn9XBBXAQsXwUCLxOiAgLeBlDJHINboqWRQdBrYOhv3XBYih73ANHzYILCWFmPHjgv2uiKGNnopbBU9DGGyxSQo8enCwmyxUQHPAAiQ5xPKTo3+WSRbBOkW3bhstUlaMftEjJqiO4aJIT3H+6SZ4WO9AYiYNjl51w6TuRpYyrGGMmcYks9i-5ghAPYHwl9XFuF-B42WgCGYgJZufLZ19b4PyGU4-eLjjlLUOcA4+biGnU0QY-VYbMX4OD6Js7ZxyDAaxgX4uB7oJFIJQWgspBCunTAcf-GIbDLmaIVM-Dm3yNkX0eczAFPi+bAsxgExs4KQlcLkeonWaTp6R1GTmcZRjd4hCJEgbOZcnYQDLlIcuTsOWaGmcUjkBd0hwvWevAAMnAJApBFGfLRbLX5WLXA4sdHin0gs57N2aZCjBPsZndJGXM2lCyJkgALMvNOjLiQsrZTy1lj8eV8v6ewuAgqt4ynhegeVOygJBF2Hsr5BznFHKeSczFwQb70CRVPB5Oz7mBoVfIAcwqFjEFpl4lF+yfaev+ZLb4QigWqsJQsUY0IaDwmqDIJS5LkXfxFAAaQKm8n+NLIEKnsP8A4vkTC5scEgQoTQHTGFeu6YwpgvwYDgCYLAI4jBdrHQAdwGPQTQABaTQ8YYIwSFb+CEUJGISD4rOrCRgd0lv3Q6NR5aQCpAJBCegQxUJe2ZL-JNeRlgfNRRAlNxbvHKtgQS0FgS01LHECsadEjgPxEhHemQyopYWQwLBzcEhiQ-F-C+bMnbR1Hog-aLeGtoDmDpGqxxOh5DKmgYE4DErjVOkvnxWI6zkBkGQDVZAQR6ihhJCAL9aaZHSxDLemAxltxcjQL4Lwu4NlQlA4WhORIhPwS5AS0AnHX0gftAGcQOhdLKQYaGBw6p5P1FJXJu9A7fBsCjPUUo5R0AAGIoCOfSBkZtEB8gICSKhxUSmONMuUDx+UxkqTaYMyajQhiPpbWUjZzyG7zNcis9FuE9n4SpeczIPTQD6ipGUiZ9AuIZD9VCfx9A1QHSSwlPRwjMR97kdaQcEygnnNU3VegMYyQ0E+eUqp9AAWoEOmC+PZSIoIujkDGqYrXsEWOvMfBZDABlKLoAYtoAAJwOiYMmVwjxrPJY2QMI+6WQCZatspHLoA8tXuMkVy7ZWCTnZnVh5ZpiH3BGZCXFduFNCoE0FNc9SxTAHqe52Exa9XvvdLhXSdmAy7ffLooTiZdjKdCQFAOgRWR3dsWM4RVH34xw83S5reQA)

Vega Code here:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "title": "Event counts",
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "labels",
      "value": true,
      "bind": {
        "input": "checkbox"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "layout",
      "value": "tidy",
      "bind": {
        "input": "radio",
        "options": [
          "tidy",
          "cluster"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "links",
      "value": "diagonal",
      "bind": {
        "input": "select",
        "options": [
          "line",
          "curve",
          "diagonal",
          "orthogonal"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "separation",
      "value": false,
      "bind": {
        "input": "checkbox"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "parent",
      "values": [
        {
          "currentNode": "rootID",
          "parent": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "tree",
      "format": {
        "property": "aggregations.table.buckets"
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.key.stk1",
          "as": "stk1"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.key.stk2",
          "as": "stk2"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.key.stk3",
          "as": "stk3"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.doc_count",
          "as": "size"
        }
      ],
      "values": {
        "took": 16,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
          "total": 3,
          "successful": 3,
          "skipped": 0,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "hits": {
          "total": 473,
          "max_score": null,
          "hits": []
        },
        "aggregations": {
          "table": {
            "after_key": {
              "stk1": "1",
              "stk2": "abc",
              "stk3": "2"
            },
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": {
                  "stk1": "3",
                  "stk2": "cde",
                  "stk3": "4"
                },
                "doc_count": 1,
                "stk1": "3",
                "stk2": "cde",
                "stk3": "4",
                "size": 1
              },
              {
                "key": {
                  "stk1": "313",
                  "stk2": "efg",
                  "stk3": "5"
                },
                "doc_count": 3,
                "stk1": "313",
                "stk2": "efg",
                "stk3": "5",
                "size": 3
              },
              {
                "key": {
                  "stk1": "313",
                  "stk2": "efg",
                  "stk3": "6"
                },
                "doc_count": 2,
                "stk1": "313",
                "stk2": "efg",
                "stk3": "6",
                "size": 2
              },
              {
                "key": {
                  "stk1": "32",
                  "stk2": "hij",
                  "stk3": "7"
                },
                "doc_count": 1,
                "stk1": "32",
                "stk2": "hij",
                "stk3": "7",
                "size": 1
              },
              {
                "key": {
                  "stk1": "32",
                  "stk2": "abc",
                  "stk3": "2"
                },
                "doc_count": 1,
                "stk1": "32",
                "stk2": "abc",
                "stk3": "2",
                "size": 1
              },
              {
                "key": {
                  "stk1": "328",
                  "stk2": "efg",
                  "stk3": "5"
                },
                "doc_count": 2,
                "stk1": "328",
                "stk2": "efg",
                "stk3": "5",
                "size": 2
              },
              {
                "key": {
                  "stk1": "328",
                  "stk2": "klm",
                  "stk3": "8"
                },
                "doc_count": 1,
                "stk1": "328",
                "stk2": "klm",
                "stk3": "8",
                "size": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "isolatedlevel1",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "stk1",
            "currentNode",
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "as": [
            "currentNode",
            "parent",
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": [
            "parent",
            "currentNode"
          ],
          "fields": [
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "ops": [
            "sum"
          ],
          "as": [
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "parent",
          "expr": "!isDefined(datum.parent) ? 'rootID':datum.parent"
        },
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "currentNode",
            "parent",
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "as": [
            "currentNode",
            "parent",
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.currentNode"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "isolatedlevel1MergedWithParent",
      "source": [
        "isolatedlevel1",
        "parent"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "isolatedlevel2",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "stk1",
            "stk2",
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "as": [
            "parent",
            "currentNode",
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": [
            "parent",
            "currentNode"
          ],
          "fields": [
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "ops": [
            "sum"
          ],
          "as": [
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "currentNode",
            "parent",
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "as": [
            "currentNode",
            "parent",
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.currentNode"
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.parent"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "isolatedlevel3",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "stk1",
            "stk2",
            "stk3",
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "as": [
            "grandparent",
            "parent",
            "currentNode",
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": [
            "parent",
            "currentNode"
          ],
          "fields": [
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "ops": [
            "sum"
          ],
          "as": [
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "currentNode",
            "parent",
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "as": [
            "currentNode",
            "parent",
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.currentNode"
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.parent"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "mergedlevels",
      "source": [
        "isolatedlevel1MergedWithParent",
        "isolatedlevel2",
        "isolatedlevel3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "parents",
      "source": [
        "mergedlevels"
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "parent"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "currentParentNode",
      "source": [
        "mergedlevels"
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "currentNode",
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "indata('parents', 'parent', datum.currentNode)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "currentLeaveNode",
      "source": [
        "mergedlevels"
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": [
            "currentNode",
            "doc_count"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "!indata('parents', 'parent', datum.currentNode)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "mergedlevelsfinal",
      "source": [
        "isolatedlevel1MergedWithParent",
        "isolatedlevel2",
        "isolatedlevel3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "vistree",
      "source": [
        "mergedlevelsfinal"
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "stratify",
          "key": "currentNode",
          "parentKey": "parent"
        },
        {
          "type": "tree",
          "method": {
            "signal": "layout"
          },
          "size": [
            {
              "signal": "height"
            },
            {
              "signal": "width - 100"
            }
          ],
          "separation": {
            "signal": "separation"
          },
          "as": [
            "y",
            "x",
            "depth",
            "children"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "links",
      "source": "vistree",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "treelinks"
        },
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "orient": "horizontal",
          "shape": {
            "signal": "links"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {
        "scheme": "magma"
      },
      "domain": {
        "data": "vistree",
        "field": "depth"
      },
      "zero": true
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {
        "data": "links"
      },
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "path": {
            "field": "path"
          },
          "stroke": {
            "value": "#ccc"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {
        "data": "vistree"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "size": {
            "value": 100
          },
          "stroke": {
            "value": "#fff"
          }
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {
            "field": "x"
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "y"
          },
          "fill": {
            "scale": "color",
            "field": "depth"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {
        "data": "vistree"
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {
            "field": "currentNode"
          },
          "fontSize": {
            "value": 9
          },
          "baseline": {
            "value": "middle"
          }
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {
            "field": "x"
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "y"
          },
          "dx": {
            "signal": "datum.children ? -7 : 7"
          },
          "align": {
            "signal": "datum.children ? 'right' : 'left'"
          },
          "opacity": {
            "signal": "labels ? 1 : 0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm pretty sure the "stratify" transform is throwing the error, but I can't seem to workout why. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this record is causing the problem:

This is because **efg** is confused to go to grandparent 328 or 313.

```
 {
                "key": {
                  "stk1": "328",
                  "stk2": "efg",
                  "stk3": "5"
                },
                "doc_count": 2,
                "stk1": "328",
                "stk2": "efg",
                "stk3": "5",
                "size": 2
              },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - You're right, I didn't realise that the second level was being linked to two different roots.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark as answered if this solved your issue.